# Problems installing tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I am using python notebooks using Anaconda for datascience and I'm trying to install tensor flow.
I have followed this tutorial:
https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

and everything is fine. I can type `import tensorflow as tf` as written and I haven't errors. But when I return to python notebooks and I write import tensorflow as tf i continue to have this error:

No module named 'tensorflow'

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should have installed Jupiter notebook within your Conda environment.

```
conda activate <your-environment-name>
conda install -c anaconda jupyter
```

This solved the same problem for me.

Comment: Thank you ... what is the environment name ?

Comment: It's the name of your conda environment, as you are using conda, I assumed you know this. Otherwise I strongly advise you to learn more about [how conda works](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/index.html). If you are following that tutorial strictly, it will probably be `tensorflow_cpu`.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to easily use your anaconda environment from jupyter notebook.

```
conda create -n myenv
source activate myenv
python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv --display-name "Python(myenv)"
```

You can now switch the kernel in jupyter notebook and import all the packages that you have installed in your conda environment.